# In Rails, what is the best way to update a record or create a new one if it doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements

I have a create statement for some models, but it’s creating a record within a join table regardless of whether the record already exists.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
@user = User.find(current_user)
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
for interest in @event.interests
 @user.choices.create(:interest => interest, :score => 4)
end
```

The problem is that it creates records no matter what. I would like it to create a record only if no record already exists; if a record does exist, I would like it to take the attribute of the found record and add or subtract 1.

I’ve been looking around have seen something called `find_or_create_by`. What does this do when it finds a record? I would like it to take the current `:score` attribute and add 1.

Is it possible to find or create by `id`? I’m not sure what attribute I would find by, since the model I’m looking at is a join model which only has `id` foreign keys and the score attribute.

I tried

```
@user.choices.find_or_create_by_user(:user => @user.id, :interest => interest, :score => 4)
```

but got

> undefined method `find_by_user`

What should I do?

Comment: Is current_user already an instance of the User model? If so, you don't need to re-find it and can just use `current_user` instead of `@user = ...`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming that the `Choice` model has a `user_id` (to associate with a user) and an `interest_id` (to associate with an interest), something like this should do the trick:

```
@user = User.find(current_user)
@event = Event.find(params[:id])

@event.interests.each do |interest|
  choice = @user.choices.find_or_initialize_by_interest_id(interest.id) do |c|
    c.score = 0 # Or whatever you want the initial value to be - 1
  end

  choice.score += 1
  choice.save!
end
```

Some notes:

1. You don't need to include the `user_id` column in the `find_or_*_by_*`, as you've already instructed Rails to only fetch `choices` belonging to `@user`.
2. I'm using `find_or_initialize_by_*`, which is essentially the same as `find_or_create_by_*`, with the one key difference being that `initialize` doesn't actually create the record. This would be similar to `Model.new` as opposed to `Model.create`.
3. The block that sets `c.score = 0` is only executed if the record does *not* exist.
4. `choice.score += 1` will update the score value for the record, regardless if it exists or not. Hence, the default score `c.score = 0` should be the initial value minus one.
5. Finally, `choice.save!` will either update the record (if it already existed) or create the initiated record (if it didn't).

Comment: linking this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747062/rails-create-or-update-magic

Comment: This answer should be updated ,some methods are not fit for rails 4

Answer (score 60):

```
my_class = ClassName.find_or_initialize_by_name(name)

my_class.update_attributes({
   :street_address => self.street_address,
   :city_name => self.city_name,
   :zip_code => self.zip_code
})
```

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted. this was helpful to me - thanks for the contribution!

Comment: I found it helpful, too. I'd guess the downvote is because it only partially addressed what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 7):

`find_or_create_by_user_id` sounds better

Comment: What is the difference tho?

Comment: this doesn't update the record?  It finds it, or it creates it.

Answer (score 3):

Also, in **Rails 3** you can do:

```
@user.choices.where(:user => @user.id, :interest => interest, :score => 4).first_or_create
```

Comment: `first_or_create` is preferred in Rails 4, meanwhile `find_or_intialize_by_xxx(attribute)` is deprecated in favor of `find_or_intialize_by(xxx:attribute)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rails 4 I don't think it creates the finder methods like it used to, so find_or_create_by_user isn't created for you. Instead you'd do it like this:

```
@user = User.find(current_user)
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
for interest in @event.interests
 @user.choices.find_or_create_by(:interest => interest) do |c|
  c.score ||= 0
  c.score += 1
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Rails 4**
You can use `find_or_create_by` to get an object(if not exist,it will create), then use `update` to save or update the record, the update method will persist record if it is not exist, otherwise update record.

For example

```
@edu = current_user.member_edu_basics.find_or_create_by(params.require(:member).permit(:school))

if @edu.update(params.require(:member).permit(:school, :majoy, :started, :ended))
```