# Rails create or update magic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a class called `CachedObject` that stores generic serialized objects indexed by a key. I want this class to implement a `create_or_update` method. If an object is found it will update it, otherwise it will create a new one.

Is there a way to do this in Rails or do I have to write my own method?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

### Rails 6

Rails 6 added an [`upsert`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-upsert) and `upsert_all` methods that deliver this functionality.

```
Model.upsert(column_name: value)
```

> [upsert] It does not instantiate any models nor does it trigger Active Record callbacks or validations.

### Rails 5, 4, and 3

Not if you are looking for an "upsert" (where the database executes an update or an insert statement in the same operation) type of statement. Out of the box, Rails and ActiveRecord have no such feature. You can use the [upsert](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert) gem, however.

Otherwise, you can use: [`find_or_initialize_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) or [`find_or_create_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by), which offer similar functionality, albeit at the cost of an additional database hit, which, in most cases, is hardly an issue at all. So unless you have serious performance concerns, I would not use the gem.

For example, if no user is found with the name "Roger", a new user instance is instantiated with its `name` set to "Roger".

```
user = User.where(name: "Roger").first_or_initialize
user.email = "email@example.com"
user.save
```

Alternatively, you can use `find_or_initialize_by`.

```
user = User.find_or_initialize_by(name: "Roger")
```

In Rails 3.

```
user = User.find_or_initialize_by_name("Roger")
user.email = "email@example.com"
user.save
```

You can use a block, but **the block only runs if the record is new**.

```
User.where(name: "Roger").first_or_initialize do |user|
  # this won't run if a user with name "Roger" is found
  user.save 
end

User.find_or_initialize_by(name: "Roger") do |user|
  # this also won't run if a user with name "Roger" is found
  user.save
end
```

If you want to use a block regardless of the record's persistence, use [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) on the result:

```
User.where(name: "Roger").first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
  user.email = "email@example.com"
  user.save
end
```

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by

Comment: The source code that the document points to shows that this doesn't work the way you imply it does - the block is passed to a new method only if the corresponding record doesn't exist. There appears to be no "upsert" magic in Rails - you have to separate it into two Ruby statements, one for the object selection and one for the attribute update.

Comment: @sameers I'm not sure I understand what you mean. What do you think I am implying?

Comment: Oh... I see what you meant now - that both forms, `find_or_initialize_by` and `find_or_create_by` accept a block. I thought you meant that whether the record exists or not, a block will be passed down with the record object as an argument, in order to do the update.

Comment: It is slightly misleading, not necessarily the answer, but the API. One would expect the block to be passed regardless, and thus could be create/updated accordingly. Instead, we have to break it out into separate statements. Boo. <3 Rails though :)

Comment: Version with `first_or_initialize.tap` works like charm. Has to make sure that params passed are ones permitted and correct.

Comment: `upsert` has been added in Rails 6. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56911694/1927876).

Answer (score 34):

In Rails 4 you can add to a specific model:

```
def self.update_or_create(attributes)
  assign_or_new(attributes).save
end

def self.assign_or_new(attributes)
  obj = first || new
  obj.assign_attributes(attributes)
  obj
end
```

and use it like

```
User.where(email: "a@b.com").update_or_create(name: "Mr A Bbb")
```

---

Or if you'd prefer to add these methods to all models put in an initializer:

```
module ActiveRecordExtras
  module Relation
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
      def update_or_create(attributes)
        assign_or_new(attributes).save
      end

      def update_or_create!(attributes)
        assign_or_new(attributes).save!
      end

      def assign_or_new(attributes)
        obj = first || new
        obj.assign_attributes(attributes)
        obj
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ActiveRecordExtras::Relation
```

Comment: Won't `assign_or_new` return the first row in the table if it exists and then that row will get updated?  It seems to be doing that for me.

Comment: `User.where(email: "a@b.com").first` will return nil if not found. Make sure you have a `where` scope

Comment: Just a note to say that `updated_at` won't be touched because `assign_attributes` is used

Comment: It won't is you're using assing_or_new but will if you use update_or_create  because of the save

Answer (score 15):

The magic you have been looking for has been added in `Rails 6`
Now you can [upsert](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-upsert) (update or insert).
For single record use:

```
Model.upsert(column_name: value)
```

For multiple records use [upsert_all](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-upsert_all) :

```
Model.upsert_all(column_name: value, unique_by: :column_name)
```

**Note**:

- **Both methods do not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations**
- **unique_by => PostgreSQL and SQLite only**

Comment: Anyone using this in production? Not working as expected for me using 6.0.33 Rails. If I have a record `[#<Model id: 1, other_model_fk: 33, some_property: 'foo'>]` and then we call `Model.upsert(other_model_fk: 33, some_property: 'bar')` then a new row is added. (the FK column is indexed by the way). The behaviour we expect _"If an object is found it will update it, otherwise it will create a new one."_ does not seem to be working. It's creating a new object. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 13):

Add this to your model:

```
def self.update_or_create_by(args, attributes)
  obj = self.find_or_create_by(args)
  obj.update(attributes)
  return obj
end
```

With that, you can:

```
User.update_or_create_by({name: 'Joe'}, attributes)
```

Comment: The second part I won't work. Can't update a single record from the class level without the ID of the record to update.

Comment: obj = self.find_or_create_by(args);  obj.update(attributes) ; return obj ;will work.

Answer (score 5):

By chaining `find_or_initialize_by` and `update`, this can be achieved in a simple way which avoids the (in my experience, often) unwanted caveats of `upsert`, and also minimises database calls.

For example:

```
Class.find_or_initialize_by(
  key: "foo",
  ...
).update(
  new_attribute: "bar",
  ...
)
```

will return you newly created or updated object.

It is worth noting that if your `find_or_initialize_by` attributes match multiple Class instances, only the 'first' one will be selected and updated.

Comment: `Modelfind_or_initialize.tap` is still better than this. The `update` here will make 2 db calls. First it will save the record with `key: foo` and then update it with new attributes. the tap will only do one db call.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but throwing my solution into the ring for completeness.
I needed this when I needed a specific find but a different create if it doesn't exist.

```
def self.find_by_or_create_with(args, attributes) # READ CAREFULLY! args for finding, attributes for creating!
        obj = self.find_or_initialize_by(args)
        return obj if obj.persisted?
        return obj if obj.update_attributes(attributes) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one statement like this:

```
CachedObject.where(key: "the given key").first_or_create! do |cached|
   cached.attribute1 = 'attribute value'
   cached.attribute2 = 'attribute value'
end
```

Comment: This won't work, since it will only return the original record if one is found. The OP asks for a solution that always changes the value, even if a record is found.

Answer (score 0):

The [sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) gem adds an [update_or_create](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/UpdateOrCreate.html) method which seems to do what you're looking for.

Comment: The question is about Active Record.

Comment: Yes, the *question* is about AR but this gives an alternate way to solve the *problem*.  It could be useful to people reading this question, who have a similar problem and may be open to using Sequel.