# Rails - create or update according to time range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table where I need to create a new entry or update if one of the columns is inside a range of dates (today).

For example, I have a table of shuttles registration with [name, time] where name represents someone and time is when he would like to take the shuttle on.
Each (name) can register at most once a day.

When someone registers, I would like to update an existing row (of the same day), if exists, or create a new one.

The following query extracts the relevant row, if exists:

```
Shuttle.where('name= ? AND time BETWEEN ? AND ?', params[:name], DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day)
```

Tried to use `first_or_create` and equivalents but couldn't find the right syntax to apply the range query.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 Shuttle.where(:name => params[:name]).
         where(:time => DateTime.now.beginning_of_day..DateTime.now.end_of_day)).
         first_or_create(:time => DateTime.now)
```

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#first_or_create

Answer (score 2):

`first_or_create` doesn't apply in this scenario, because the condition doesn't make sense as the value of an update.  It would be like saying "Find a shuttle where the time is any time on this given day, and if you don't find one then create one where the time is any time on this given day".  That doesn't make sense: you need a specific time when you create a shuttle.

You need to think about the logic of what you want to do: it's not obvious to me at least.

Comment: You're basically right. However, a shuttle is [name, time] where each 'name' can register once a day. If someone already registered at a given day, I would like to update the hour to the new value.

Comment: You should add this info to your question, with an example.

Comment: first_or_initialize won't work -- you need a hash of parameters in your where clause that can be used to set attributes for first_or_initialize.  IE, Shuttle.where(:name => params[:name]).first_or_initialize will work, but Shuttle.where("name = :name", :name => params[:name]") will not

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, I would do the following

```
@shuttle = Shuttle.where('name= ? AND time BETWEEN ? AND ?', params[:name], DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day).first
@shuttle.columnname = "new value"
@shuttle.save
```

If you are doing multiple

```
@shuttles = Shuttle.where('name= ? AND time BETWEEN ? AND ?', params[:name], DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day)
@shuttles.each do |shuttle|
  shuttle.columnname = "new value"
  shuttle.save
end
```

Comment: that's fine for updating, but he is trying to do a `first_or_create`.  (which doesn't make sense, but that's what he asked).  Also your code will raise an exception on line 2 if @shuttle = nil.

Comment: exactly, I'll need to create if not exists.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
@shuttle = Shuttle.where(
      name: params[:name],
      time: DateTime.now.beginning_of_day..DateTime.now.end_of_day
    ).first_or_initialize do |s|
  s.attribute = value
  s.save
end
```

Comment: Looks good, I'll need to try in order to see if it works. What's 'value' in this context?

Comment: The value is what ever you want it to be. Since you want to create the object if it's not found, you should know the value you want to give it. It's just an example of how to set a property value on the object whether it's new or persisted: `s.foo = "whatever"`

Comment: @LiorOhana see this for an exmaple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747062/rails-create-or-update-magic/18747148#18747148

Comment: My problem with find_or_initialize_by is that I can't get the right syntax for applying the time range query.