# Rails 4 not updating record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I've just migrated from mongoid to postgres and I am obviously now using ActiveRecord. I run a Cron job which simply updates products from a supplier list but for some reason it isn't working

Here's the code:

```
        insert = CSV.foreach(tempfilename, col_sep: ',', headers: true) do |row|
          item = Product.find_or_create_by(line_item: row['line_item']) do |product|
            product.supplier = "Supplier Name",
            product.supplier_product_id = row['supplier_product_id'],
            product.supplier_link = row['supplier_link'],
            product.supplier_image_url = row['supplier_image_url']
          end
          item.save
        end
```

Comment: Use `item.save!` - if the records cannot be saved, an error will be thrown and the message will tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Are items found? Is validation passing? Are there DB errors?

Comment: eugen - I've tried save! Still didn't work

Comment: Dave - Items are found and it iterates as it should. There is no validation. Rollback only happens at the end of existing records being found. So actually only creates on first run.

Comment: the `save` or `save!` call is actually completely reundant. `find_or_create` will already have saved the record

Comment: meagar - But the rest is okay?

Comment: I ended up using the Rails 4 code I managed to find here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18747148/3225563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

&block is executed only when record was not found

```
def find_or_create_by(attributes, &block)
      find_by(attributes) || create(attributes, &block)
    end
```

Comment: Thanks Evgeny! I had just found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18747148/3225563 which helped.