# How to create a record or edit it if a record with the same attributes already exists in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Specifically, a record has and belongs to many users, and a user can either create the record or, if it already exists, add himself to the users the record has.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails create or update magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747062/rails-create-or-update-magic)

Comment: That's maybe the same question, but the answer explains only how you create or find a record, not how you would create or edit one.

Answer (score 0):

In the **User** model defines these two methods:

```
def self.update_or_create(attributes)
  assign_or_initialize(attributes).save  
end

def self.assign_or_initialize(attributes)
  obj = first || new
  obj.assign_attributes(attributes)
  obj
end
```

and then you can use it likes this:

```
User.where(email: "test@example.com").update_or_create(name: "abc")
```