# How to get out from the create action if value exist and only need to update in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I get out from the create action and only update the object if it was discarded?

I am using rails 5, I have seen before there was an option for create_or_update, but that one was deprecated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think what you're looking is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747062/rails-create-or-update-magic

Answer (score 1):

To "get out from" a controller action you probably want to `render` a template (on failure so you can perhaps try again) or `redirect_to` (on success) to another controller action.  Without seeing your code it's hard to say much more.