# Ruby on rails: How to create single api for create and update both actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a api which creates a contact

```
def create
   @account = Account.find_by(api_token: params[:api_token])
   @user = @account.users.find_by(role: 'owner')
   @contact = @user.contacts.new(contact_params)
   respond_to do |format|
     if @contact.save
       format.json { render json: @contact }
     else
       format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
```

contact_params has `email, user_id, name` attributes

I have association like this

in user model

```
belongs_to: account, has_many :contacts
```

in account model

```
has_many :users
```

in contact model

```
belongs_to :user
```

I want to create an api which can do both create a new contact and if contact is available then should update the contact params without any route changes.

I have used this route

resources :contacts, only: [:create]

and for above api i am using this URI pattern
`/contact?api_token=param[:api_token]`

so, how can i solve this problem.

Comment: in one action add condition and check whether contact exists. If so - update it, else - create it, pretty simple I guess

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747062/rails-create-or-update-magic

Comment: `api_token` sounds like credential data. If so, don't send it as part of the URL.