# Check for duplicate record and then create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an rails app wherein am trying to either downvote or upvote an contact. I have a user model powered by devise. I have an feedback model too in place which stores which user has upvoted/downvoted an contact. How do I get to insert record into the feedback table when two users are trying to upvote/downvote the same contact details?

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Rails, what is the best way to update a record or create a new one if it doesn't exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621208/in-rails-what-is-the-best-way-to-update-a-record-or-create-a-new-one-if-it-does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Contract.find_or_create_by(name: 'xyz') do |contract|
  contract.user_id = current_user.id
end
```

In the above code you have two case

Case 1) Contract name xyz exists in this case that contract will be updated with a id of current user

Case 2) Contract name xyz doesn't exists in this case a new contract will be created with a id of current user

More information can be found in [Api Dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by)